# How to get the SHA of the base commit a branch is started from?

Tags: git, branch, git-commit, sha

```
C    E
|   /
B  D
| /
A
```

How to get the SHA of the commit `A` if `E` is the current `HEAD`?

Comment: See `git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph`

Comment: Even `git log --all` does the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If finding the common ancestor of the branches C and E is what you need, then:

```
git merge-base <hash of commit C> <hash of commit E>
```

Answer (score 3):

When trying to get SHA of base commit for a current branch this is useful:

```
git merge-base --fork-point <main branch>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see `git log [options]` and find the started commit of a specific branch.

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph
```